# How to get query conversation messages from Digital Engagement channel?

Tags: facebook, digital-engagement, messagingsession

How can we retrieve messages from Facebook digital engagement channel?
Little bit more context on it:

- We have digital engagement plugin enabled in salesforce and connected
  with Facebook.
- Requirement is to have process chat messages in Apex or 3rd party app.

So I run some analyzing of how Salesforce Digital engagement works internally:
It is querying messages from some endpoint

"serviceComponent://ui.liveagent.components.aura.controller.EndedChatController/ACTION$getSelectedConversationData",

but I don't find any API or field available to retrieve conversation transcript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run following query

```
[
SELECT Id, ActorType, ActorId, ActorName, Message, MessageStatus, MessageStatusCode, MessageSendTime, MessageDeliverTime, MessageReadTime, MessageIdentifier, HasAttachments 

FROM ConversationEntry 

WHERE ActorId = <User or MessagingEndUser> AND ConvesationId = '0Mw0XXXXXXXX...']
```

In digital engagement records have following relations as on picture

[image: Digital Engagement Entity relation]